# All the rich:editors in the form disappear when clicked on 'styles' drop-down

Tags: jsf, richfaces, rich-text-editor

I'm using rich faces 4 with jsf 2.2
Here is rich text editor tag I'm using:

```
<rich:editor toolbar="custom"
    id="exampleId" style="width:100%" viewMode="visual">
    <f:facet name="config">
    toolbar_custom:
   [
    { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items : ['Table'] },
    { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Strike','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize' ] }
   ]
</f:facet>
</rich:editor>
```

I have included following header in the xhtml file:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
```

Comment: What happens to the the generated HTML? Any errors in the console? What version of RichFaces are you using? Have you tried modifying the toolbar to see what happens?

Comment: I'm using rich faces 4 with jsf 2.2 (also edited the post). Real problem is sometimes RTEs disappear, sometimes they don't.

Comment: It's probably not a RichFaces problem but I want to know the exact version, e.g. 4.5.17. How do they disappear? Does the visibility change (and if so on which element?) or is the component removed from the page entirely? Any errors?

Comment: Problem seem to have gone for now. I will observe console errors and generated HTML and let you know when it occurs again. BTW Its richfaces-4.5.15

Comment: I've noticed that following class is the reason:  .cke {
    visibility: hidden;
} But in some cases it is overridden by class cke_chrome and everything works fine.

Comment: That looks like a problem with the editor, have you tried different browsers?